# Is there a better way to evaluate the flux of a sphere not centered at the origin?

Tags: integration, divergence-operator, change-of-variable

I am supposed to evaluate the flux with the vector field:

$F=x^{2}i+y^{2}j+z^{2}k$, outward across the boundary of the given solid region

the ball: $(x-2)^2 + (y)^2 +(z-3)^2 \le 3^2$

The reason i'm asking is because this is how the evaluated the flux in my book:

[image]

However I am unfamiliar with this method.

How could I approach this differently with translation?

I'm was thinking that I could translate $u =x-2$ and likewise for the other variables y,z.

Then translate this into spherical coordinates. Is the thinking somewhat correct?

Comment: If you translate your coordinate system, the sphere becomes centered at the new origin but the vector field gets spoiled. You can definitely calculate the flux using the definition (dot multiply your vector field on the sphere by the unit normal vector and integrate over the sphere, which you can parametrize using two spherical angles). In your book, the Divergence Theorem is used, and it makes the computation absolutely trivial.

Comment: @GReyes Why would the vector field get spoiled? I am also supposed to use the Divergence Theorem, but I am just unsure howI would treat my off-centered sphere.

Comment: If you take your new coordinates $u=x-2$, $v=y$, $w=z-3$, your sphere is centered at the origin $u^2+v^2+w^2=9$. Your vector field becomes $((u+2)^2, v^2,(w+3)^2)$.

Comment: In these new coordinates the unit normal vector is just $(u/3,v/3,w/3)$ on the sphere. When you dot-multiply by the field you get some polynomial that you have to express through (say) the spherical angles. Then you integrate over the sphere, taking the surface element $dS=9\sin\phi\, d\phi\,d\theta$. Not so bad, just a bunch of (simple) trigonometric integrals.